# Create a Python recursive function that prints all the integers less than or equal to the value provided in the original call

Tags: recursion

```
i=0
def recursiveIntegers(n):
    if n==1:
       return 1;
    else:
       reqval= n-1;
       print("less than or equal to the original -->",reqval);
       return recursiveIntegers(reqval)

userValue = int(input("Enter value "))

recursiveIntegers(userValue)
```

What am i missing for this to print out equal values..?

Answer (score 0):

Print 'n' first ... then do that 'reqval = n-1'